# R Programming, How to filter, then sum?

Tags: r, loops, filter, sum

I imported a csv with 4 columns into RStudio
I created a data.frame "dat" with 4 variables

"count..."        # not using
"CategoryBudget"  # dollar value
"Category"        # name of various categories
"Location"        # city names

Within each location, there are multiple category names, each with their own CategoryBudget.

I want to sum CategoryBudget of all categories within each location
and print a list of locations with CategoryBudget sum.

Within each location, I want the sum of Category budget for every Category
Then print location name, category name, sum of CategoryBudget for each category name.

I am just starting out with R and would appreciate any help.

> ```
>  count... CategoryBudget                  Category               Location
> ```
>
> 1     2110       6379.274                  used car dealers      chicago
>
> 2     2083       6234.621                   new car dealers      chicago
>
> 3     1972       6052.865       automotive sales & services      chicago
>
> 4     1712       4809.133                  used car dealers     los angeles
>
> 5     1477       4530.553          auto parts & accessories      chicago
>
> 6     1415       4339.386                   new car dealers     los angeles

Comment: It will be good to know if you could solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, rnso provided the solution the worked for me.  Very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'aggregate' can be used as follows:

```
> dd
  count CategoryBudget                    Category    Location
1  2110       6379.274            used_car_dealers     chicago
2  2083       6234.621             new_car_dealers     chicago
3  1972       6052.865 automotive_sales_&_services     chicago
4  1712       4809.133            used_car_dealers los_angeles
5  1477       4530.553    auto_parts_&_accessories     chicago
6  1415       4339.386             new_car_dealers los_angeles
> 
> aggregate(count~Location, dd, sum)
     Location count
1     chicago  7642
2 los_angeles  3127

> aggregate(CategoryBudget~Location, dd, sum)
     Location CategoryBudget
1     chicago      23197.313
2 los_angeles       9148.519
> 

> aggregate(CategoryBudget~Location+Category, dd, sum)
     Location                    Category CategoryBudget
1     chicago automotive_sales_&_services       6052.865
2     chicago    auto_parts_&_accessories       4530.553
3     chicago             new_car_dealers       6234.621
4 los_angeles             new_car_dealers       4339.386
5     chicago            used_car_dealers       6379.274
6 los_angeles            used_car_dealers       4809.133
>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the aggregate function. Try

```
condensedData <- aggregate(dat, by=list(Location), FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```